# How to solve a Fredholm equation with known $\lambda$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I have the Fredholm equation,

$$\phi(x)=\sin x+\lambda\int_0^\pi\cos(x/2-3y)\phi(y)dy$$

and would like to solve it.

First, I found  using the precondition for contraction of the Fredholm operator: $$|\lambda|<\frac{1}{M(b-a)}$$

That $|\lambda|<\sqrt{2}$ to give a contraction. So I insert 1 as a value for $\lambda$ and get:

$$\phi(x)=\sin x+\int_0^\pi\cos(x/2-3y)\phi(y)dy$$

I solved this numerically using Mathematica. The solution is $\phi(x)=\sin(x)$. However, how can I solve this "by hand"?

Thanks

Comment: Hint : use the formula for $\cos(a-b)$ you get $\phi(x)=\sin x+\lambda C_1\cos(x/2)+\lambda C_2\sin(x/2)$ since the remaining integrals are constants due to fixed boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the second derivative of $\phi(x)$
$$\begin{align}
\phi''(x) = \frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}(x) &= -\sin(x)+\lambda\int_0^{\pi}  \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\cos(x/2-3y)  \right)}_{=-\frac{1}{4}\cos(x/2-3y)} \phi(y)dy \\
  &=-\sin(x)-\frac{\lambda}{4}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(x/2-3y) \phi(y)dy \\
&=-\sin(x)-\frac{1}{4}  \underbrace{\left(\lambda\int_0^{\pi} \cos(x/2-3y) \phi(y)dy \right)}_{=\phi(x)-\sin(x)}  \\
&=-\sin(x)-\frac{1}{4} \left(\phi(x)-\sin(x)  \right) \\
\phi''(x)&=-\frac{1}{4} \phi(x) -\frac{3}{4}\sin(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
The equation $(1)$ can be [solved easily](http://www.math.pitt.edu/%7Eathanas/MATH-0230-CALCULUS-II/notes-diffeq.pdf), the general solution is
$$\phi(x) = \sin(x) + c_1 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)+ c_2 \cos\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)$$

Comment: What happened to $\phi(y)$)?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz We compute the second derivative respected to $x$ : $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$, so $\phi(y)$ in the integrand is just a constant

Comment: Is that what "became" $\phi(x)$?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz I add an intermediate step, hope it's useful

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Perhaps it's clearer now?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Whether $\lambda = 1$ or not, the solution is the same. And perhaps you wan to know how to solve the equation $(1)$? If yes, just read the link I added. Indeed, $(1)$ is a "Nonhomogeneous Second-Order Differential Equations" and can be solved analytically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140668/discussion-between-luthier415hz-and-nn2).

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks!!